# Using a displaylink usb video adapter

Tags: 10.10, usb, display, monitor, displaylink

I just bought [this USB graphics adapter](http://www.hi-techitaly.com/news/computer/2501-bestit-itek-uga-connettere-fino-a-6-monitor-allo-stesso-computer.html) and I need to use it on Ubuntu 10.10. I [followed this guide](http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/), but when I ran

```
$ ./configure && sudo make install && make check
```

nothing happened. On Windows, after the installation the monitor was detected automatically.

How do I get it to work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Install the `xserver-xorg-video-displaylink` to add drivers for this display.

You will need to configure the monitor by creating an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.  Instructions can be found in `/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink/examples/`

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04, xorg.conf examples are here instead: /usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink/README

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this:  http://blogg.noonday.se/2010/01/28/linux-usb-video-adapter/

This guy did it and gave the steps on how he did it...

Comment: I tried but do not works.