# Using a DisplayLink USB video adapter on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb, video, display, 12.10, displaylink

The line of USB video adapters made by DisplayLink has a somewhat sordid history under Linux. In past Ubuntu releases, the process of getting them to work has been somewhat difficult, inspiring a number of past questions on this site:

[example 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25597/using-a-displaylink-usb-video-adapter)
[example 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40031/how-do-i-use-a-displaylink-monitor)
[example 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98916/how-do-i-configure-a-displaylink-usb-monitor)

However, there are [some indications](http://www.zdnet.com/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-review-7000005929/) that version 3.5 of the Linux kernel (which is used by 12.10) contains better support for these adapters, which should make them easier to use. I currently have a single-GPU machine (it is an Nvidia adapter) with dual monitor outputs. I would like to add the DisplayLink adapter to drive a third external monitor. How can I set this up on Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: I hope someone gets this working.  It would be nice to have a "this displaylink adapter works" post somewhere.

Comment: @hbdgaf Seconded. I'll pay whatever they ask for one of these that works.

Answer (score 4):

I just added "blacklist udl" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf

and commented out "blacklist udlfb" from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf

This was enough to get the monitor to display the green screen of success.

After that it's just a matter of setting up xorg.conf in the same way as previous Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I also confirm it got it working (green screen at least!) for me too (Ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: Sadly, that did not help me at all.

Comment: I have this issue, but I do not know how to set-up my xorg.conf "like in previous versions". Link to tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get from green-screen to a static-image under Ubuntu 12.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/393117/46709